# Почему возвращает undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var
    fs  = require('fs'),
    dir = "header.html";

function getFile(dir) {
  var res;

  fs.stat(dir, function(err, stats) {

    if(err)
      return console.log(err);

    fs.readFile(dir, function(err, data) {
      res = new Buffer( data );
    });

  });

  return res;
}

console.log( getFile(dir) );
```

Данный код возвращает `undefined` и никак не пойму почему же это происходит. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Suvitruf, откатил изменение, как незначительные, без примера как именно пробовал автор вопроса - приписка только сбивает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы изспользуете асинхронныые функции (всякая функция с коллбэком, как правило, асинхронная). Сам их смысл в том, что результат их работы вы можете получить только внутри коллбэка. Результат работы `fs.stat()` доступен внутри её коллбэка и перередаётся там `fs.readFile()`, а результат работы `fs.readFile()` доступен уже только внутри её коллбэка, второго уровня вложенности, и т.д. Когда вы возвращаете `return res;`, `fs.stat()` ещё не окончила работу, а `fs.readFile()` ещё даже не начала, поэтому значение `res` возвращается сразу после объявления, когда оно всё ещё `undefined`. Получить содержимое файла и вывести его в `console.log()` можно только внутри самого глубокого коллбэка:

```js
var
    fs  = require('fs'),
    dir = "header.html";

function getFile(dir) {
  fs.stat(dir, function(err, stats) {

    if(err)
      return console.log(err);

    fs.readFile(dir, function(err, data) {
      var res = new Buffer( data );
      console.log(res);
    });

  });
}

getFile(dir);
```

Синхронный вариант:

```
'use strict';

var
    fs  = require('fs'),
    dir = "header.html";

function getFile(dir) {
  var stats = fs.statSync(dir);
  var res = fs.readFileSync(dir);
  return res;
}

console.log( getFile(dir) );
```

Comment: Почему же тогда даже при использовании синхронных функций, все равно возвращает undifined. Я заменил stat на statSync, а readFile на readFileSync, но результат не изменился

Comment: Я добавил в конец ответа синхронный вариант. Сверьте, совпадает ли он с вашим.